# Using InfluxDB difference function

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have some measurement data in my influxdb database which I can query with:

`select * from E_real_con`
name: E_real_con
time                value
----                -----
1537920001044785525 | 57160036.00
1538006401069651036 | 57227208.00
1538092800108297103 | 57294112.00
1538179200697333731 | 57366108.00

However, "value" is a cumulative value and I would like to get the delta/difference between two consecutive values.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT difference(last(value)) FROM E_real_con WHERE time >= now() - 7d GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ERR: unsupported difference iterator type: *query.stringInterruptIterator
```

I would be happy to get some hints and feedback how to solve my issue.

I am using influxdb 1.6.1

Thanks a lot!
Christoph

Comment: In the meantime I figured out, that the field "value" was of type "string". I used the command "SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM E_real_con" to show the field types for anyone interested. I deleted the old values and now "value" is of type "float". So the error message "ERR: unsupported difference iterator type: *query.stringInterruptIterator" is gone but there are still no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. The following two mistakes had to be corrected:

1) The values in the measurement were of type "string" and not "float". As the data was coming from nodered, I cleared the database and used parseFloat() in nodered before writing the data to influxdb. 
BTW: you can check the datatype of your measurement field by:

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM E_real_con
```

2) It seems that the query command requires a "where"

This works:

```
SELECT difference(last(value)) FROM E_real_del WHERE time >= now() - 7d GROUP BY time(1d)
```

whereas:

```
SELECT difference(last(value)) FROM E_real_del GROUP BY time(1d)
```

does not work.

I hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) It seems that the query command requires a "where"

It's even more restricted than that. It requires a where with a minimum timestamp.

For example, the following gives me no result:

```
select difference(last(value)) from WaterConsumption_Total where time < now() - 1d group by time(1d) fill(previous)
```

While this does:

```
select difference(last(value)) from WaterConsumption_Total where time > '2019-08-23T00:00:00Z' group by time(1d) fill(previous)
```

This effectively makes it impossible to use such a query as a continuous query.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's working under the hood, but I'm successfully using `difference()` in a CQ in InfluxDB 1.8

Comment: `CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_raw_growth_factor ON mymeas BEGIN SELECT mean(new_items) / (mean(new_items) - difference(mean(new_items))) AS raw_growth_factor INTO mymeas.autogen.mydb_calcs FROM mymeas.autogen.mydb WHERE time > '2000-01-01T00:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(1d), location, code END`

Comment: According to the docs, the `WHERE time > x` clause gets silently stripped, but I left it in there so I could copy / paste as needed.