# Using InfluxDB difference function in Python

Tags: python, influxdb

Extending this [Using InfluxDB difference function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566289/using-influxdb-difference-function) a bit further, I have

```
select difference("e") from Energy where time >= now() - 24h
```

or

```
select difference("e") from Energy where time >=
'2020-04-14T00:00:01Z' and time <= '2020-04-15T20:00:01Z'
```

both working where the time search only covers 2 datapoints for the subtraction.

But how do I achieve this in a python script? The best I have is

```
response = client.query(select difference("e") from Energy where time
>= now() - 24h)
```

but it returns an Invalid syntax error.
Any clues to implement difference() in python?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole query has to a python string. Try something like:

```
response = client.query('select difference("e") from Energy where time >= now() - 24h')
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes in bash this works: `influx -database EnergTotal -execute 'select difference("e") from Energy where time >= now() - 24h'` but getting the syntax right for python is a challenge as it requires the database name. I have tried a niumber of options around `response = client.query('database=EnergTotal select difference("e") from Energy where time >= now() - 24h')` without success.

Answer (score 0):

The query has to be first and then the database name:

```
response = client.query('select difference("e") from Energy where time >= now() - 24h', database='EnergTotal')
```

Hope this helps some others. And thanks @rolf82.